# Javascript: Module is not defined (UMD Format module)

Tags: javascript, undefined, onload, umd

Working with Rollupjs, I try to run my module on my index.html page

```js
<script type="module" src="./bundle.js" ></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const lib = new MyLibrary();
    console.log(lib);
  });
</script>
```

and I get the following error:

> (index):17 Uncaught ReferenceError: MyLibrary is not defined

The module format is UMD. Thanks!

Comment: `<script type="module">` does not make sense for a UMD module.

Answer (score 0):

How about making sure your module is loaded before your scripts. I think you should try loading the first script with `async` or `defer` flag. E.g.

With `defer`

```js
<script defer type="module" src="./bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const lib = new MyLibrary();
    console.log(lib);
  });
</script>
```

With `async`

```js
<script async type="module" src="./bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const lib = new MyLibrary();
    console.log(lib);
  });
</script>
```

Also make sure you check `MyLibrary` class is loaded. For example you can use browser developer console and type the class name, which is `MyLibrary` and if it shows up that means the module is loaded. If it says undefined... You know you got a problem with loading the script. Probably related to `parcel` config. If you still have problems please share your bundler code and directory structure  image.